# Better word than complexity

Tags: word-request, synonyms

I am translating my math game to english and I am struggling with a translation of one word. Translation tools offer me "complexity" but I feel it does not match my context well. It holds options like "Easy", "Normal" or "Hard". Is it really the complexity?

Other context: "First solved task with normal or easier complexity"

Comment: You may want to consider the word [difficulty](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DifficultyLevels) for this purpose.

Comment: **Difficulty levels** is the most popular term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrases you may be looking for are

> degrees of difficulty
>   level of difficulty
>
> There are different *levels of difficulty*: Easy, Normal, and Hard.
>   First solve the task with a lower *level of difficulty*.